# What is the best online place (forum, board etc.) to *discuss* a statistical question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

The official rule on CrossValidated is:

> **How to Ask**
> Is your question about statistics?
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
> Provide details. Share your research.

What is the best place (forum, board etc) to ask a question (related to data science, data mining, image/video recognition) that cannot be just answered but discussed instead?

This is the actual question:

> I have a non-commercial project in mind related to getting data from huge numbers of live-showing web-cameras and analyzing the records with ML (object and movement recognition).
>
> I need a person/persons who can write a code and build the pipeline that allows to record live video from a specific website and to place all records on hard-drive. For example, I have a link to the webpage with live translation and I provide this link to this application (that have to be developed) and this application starts to record the translation and store it somewhere. And this app should be scalable and be able to work with one link (one camera) and 10000 links (10000 cameras) and do recording during 24 hours.
>
> Also, I need a person/persons who can write a code that allows to analyze all the videos that have been recorded. By analyzing I mean counting a number of objects in the record, tracking object movement etc.
>
> It is a non-commercial project. I cannot actually pay for this but I hope that I can encourage them to participate.
>
> And there is a question I came with. Where can I find these kinds of persons? Is there any live data science community where I can register and ask if someone wants to participate in my project? As a data scientist at the beginner of his career, I am not aware of this kind of community.
>
> I took a lot of courses on Coursera and DataCamp. I have tried to reach the teachers who I believe can help me and give me kind of direction to move. But I realize that it is almost impossible to reach a person using emails, social networks etc. They just do not reply. So I am here and asking for your advice.

Comment: This (meta.CV) is now the right place to ask this question. But your question isn't very clear. Can you say more about what you have in mind?

Comment: I just updated the main message.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41959/is-so-an-inappropriate-venue-for-assembling-a-development-team-for-a-new-project for some possibilities.

Comment: Guru.com is a site for all types of developers with expertise in many software languages and platforms willing to work on a consulting basis.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. I will check out that thread and Guru

Comment: -1 because the edit seems to have nothing to do with the title or original question. My assessment of the problem is that you need to hire a consultant. There are many contract research groups out there who do this kind of work, and googling yields a lot of results all over the globe.

Comment: @AdamO That's a little harsh, because we have to know what kind of question is in mind before we can advise on where to ask it. I'd just comment further that there are many kinds of collaboration that don't involve a consultant, but many of us would be wary of working with a stranger for free and not trivially when there are so many people we already know or know about who identifiably have complementary skills or expertise and are known to be congenial personally.